# Need assistance with getCartTotal()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-applications

I am having a little problem with some java code I am working on in eclipse to make a mobile app shopping site sort of doohicky lol...

The rest of my code is fine but I am struggling a little with the shopping cart. So far I have managed to get the shopping cart to operate across the who application using the "extends Application" line, and how to retrive a product from the cart based on a product Id.

Now what I am struggling with is how to use the getCartTotal() to extract the cost of the products in the cart and produce a subtotal and show it to the user before proceeding to the checkout.

Any Ideas?

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated :)

*EDIT* To those who are replying that this is "limited code" I only pasted in the section I am struggling with... plus I am doing my work in the eclipse program where all the class objects are in separate sections.

To Christina: Yes I was asking for help on how to figure out the algorithm, I will look at pamphlets answer and see if this will help me :) Thank you.

```
package uk.ac.uk.st265.shopper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Application;

public class ShopperApp extends Application {

public List<Product> cart =  new ArrayList<Product>(); 

Product findInCart(int id){
    for (int i=0; i < cart.size(); i++){
        Product p = cart.get(i);
        if (p.getProductId() == id)
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Loop over the items in the cart adding their prices to a local variable that you return at the end?

Comment: You don't currently have any code written for getCartTotal(). Are you asking for help figuring out an algorithm? (if so, see @pamphlet 's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pamphlet suggested:

```
public double getCartTotal() {
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    for(Product p: cart) {
        totalPrice += p.getProductPrice();
    }
    return totalPrice;
}
```